# Rent tokens and still receive airdrops?

Tags: tokens, airdrops

It seems that renting one's token comes at the additional cost of missing airdrops. Will there be any way to still receive airdrops while leasing out tokens?

Comment: Where did you read this information, can you provide a source?

Comment: Would that mean if you are the person renting the token that you get the airdrop?

Answer (score 3):

Some airdrops like HorusPay will airdrop only to genesis block holders. That means If you had your tokens the day of the snapshot, you will get 1:1 ratio according to your eos tokens.

Otherwise like said on https://www.chintai-eos.io/, your tokens are moved to a leasing contract address. That means you're not in control of your tokens while they're being rented.

[image]

Comment: So basically, it depends on the rules set up by any specific airdrop.